# Error in Msbuild.exe for static enum class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, c#-5.0

I have enums added in the static partial class (Helper.cs). When i reference this enum in other files, automatically using block is added like  - "**using static Common.Util.Helper**"

So If i do msbuild from folder - "**Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe**" its not working and giving an error like below -

> error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'static' is a keyword

But in VS 2015 it builds fine. I am using VS 2015 and Framework version 4.5. So do i need to any settings in msbuild or any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Remove `static` from your using statement

Comment: Actually speaking, I dont want to do that as i have referred this class in so many places and this change leads me to change in all the places. Rather i would like to see some solution in relates to MSBuild as this code works in VS 2015 !!

Comment: Well `using static` was introduced in `c#6.0` and you've tagged your question with `c#5.0` so if your truly working in version 5 then that's your only option

Comment: What is the `ToolsVersion` and `TargetFrameworkVersion` you are using in your MSBuild script?

Comment: How do check the version of C# being used ? and TargetFrameworkVersion - 4.5 and x64 and I did not get what you mean by Toolsversion ?

Comment: at the very beginning of your MSBuild script you should have a line that looks similar to this `<Project DefaultTargets="Start" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">`

Comment: <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137179/discussion-between-abhijith-nayak-and-callback-kid).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

instead.

Comment: Nice. It worked for me. What is the difference between these two ?

Comment: This one uses the build tools that Visual Studio 2015 uses, including the `csc.exe` compiler for c# 6.

Comment: Do i need to refer the same path to build the x64 dll ?

Comment: 32-bit MSbuild works  just fine for producing 64-bit output assemblies.

Comment: Everytime i am getting 32 bits dll when i build using MSbuild with the above mentioned Path. I have set a Platform as x64 but when I build using MSBuild I am getting X86 dll (I am checking in Notepad it is PE L) But when i build in VS 2015 for the same project it shows PE dt i.e, 64 bits dll)

Comment: Do you pass configuration and platform values using the /p switch after msbuild.exe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137187/discussion-between-abhijith-nayak-and-weir).